# Who has considered the LCM of the multiplicative order of the divisors of p-1, where p is a prime, for which p-1 is square free?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, multiplicative-order

A colleague of mine and I have been considering the behavior of divisors of p-1 with respect to multiplicative order in Z/(p), for primes p with p-1 square free. The least common-multiple of the orders of the divisors of p-1, which we call L(p), crops up naturally, and we are hoping someone can give references to this concept. In particular, we would like to know whether or not it is known if it is true that L(p)= p-1, whenever there is no divisor of p-1 whose order is L(p).

Comment: It should be noted that $L(p)=p-1$ iff $p$ has a primitive root whose prime divisors divide $p-1$ (and this does not suppose $p-1$ is square-free)

Comment: This doesn't really answer your question, but the function you are studying is related to the [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function). That might be a good place to start.

Comment: There is always a primitive root, a number whose order is p-1, so the Carmichael number will always be p-1.

Comment: What I meant was that maybe the techniques used to study the Carmichael function have some bearing on your $L(p)$ function.

Comment: @Kyle Oh I see. That seems like a good idea.